# Select a DT row and then change the value of one cell of this row based on widget selection input and actionButton() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app below and I when I click on a row I want to be able to select it and then change the value of a selected column of this row by the relative widget in the left sidebhar after pressing the `actionButton() Edit`. For example if I click on the 2nd row and then change the `Security Type` widget from `Stock` to `Load Fund` the `Security Type` column of the 2nd row should become `Load Fund`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tibble)
Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  "$10,000",
  "$8,000", "$10,000"
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F, collapsed = F,
      selectInput(
        "sectype", "Security Type",
        c(unique(Input$`Security Type`))
      ),
      selectInput(
        "sectick", "Ticker",
        c(unique(Input$Ticker))
      ),
      dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
      dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
      selectInput(
        "aminv", "Amount Invested",
        c(unique(Input$`Amount Invested`))
      ),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit")
      
      
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3("Results"),
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "InsiderTraining",
          dataTableOutput("TBL1")
        )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # Init with some example data
    data <- reactiveVal(Input)
    
    
   
    observeEvent(input$edit,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {

      }
    })
    output$TBL1 <- renderDataTable(
      data(),selection="single"
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can save the rendered table inside a `reactiveValues` object along with the row that was selected:

```
rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL)
```

Second, every time the `edit` button get's pressed, the row selected is saved and de data updated using `walk2` to loop through all the columns.

```
  observeEvent(input$edit,{
    
    if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
      cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
      colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
      "remember the row selected"
      rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
      
      walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
      
    }
  
    })
```

App:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  "$10,000",
  "$8,000", "$10,000"
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
  options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    minified = F, collapsed = F,
    selectInput(
      "sectype", "Security Type",
      c(unique(Input$`Security Type`))
    ),
    selectInput(
      "sectick", "Ticker",
      c(unique(Input$Ticker))
    ),
    dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
    dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
    selectInput(
      "aminv", "Amount Invested",
      c(unique(Input$`Amount Invested`))
    ),
    actionButton("edit", "Edit")
    
    
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    h3("Results"),
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs",
      tabPanel(
        "InsiderTraining",
        dataTableOutput("TBL1")
      )
    )
  ),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
  title = "DashboardPage"
))


server = function(input, output) {
  # I want to remember the row that was selected 
  rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL)
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$edit,{
    
    if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
      cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
      colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
      "remember the row selected"
      rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
      
      walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
      
    }
  
    })
  
  
  output$TBL1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(rv$df, selection = list(target = "row",  selected = rv$row_selected))
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: I like our answer and accepted it but I wanted to combine with more functionalitites at the same dataset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186250/add-remove-and-edit-rows-in-a-dtdatatable-of-a-shiny-app

Comment: Could you take a look at this shiny issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023022/create-a-dynamic-table-on-shiny-app-based-on-shiny-widget-and-row-selection-of-a