# Add, remove and edit rows in a DT::datatable of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app below in which I can add a new row by pressing `Add` based on the shiny widgets selection, I can select and delete one row by pressing `Delete` and I want to combine with them the functionality of clicking on a row and then change the value of a selected column of this row by the relative widget in the left sidebar after pressing the  `Edit`. For example if I click on the 2nd row and then change the `Security Type` widget from `Stock` to `Load Fund` the `Security Type` column of the 2nd row should become `Load Fund`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tibble)
Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  "$10,000",
  "$8,000", "$10,000"
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F, collapsed = F,
      selectInput(
        "sectype", "Security Type",
        c(unique(Input$`Security Type`))
      ),
      selectInput(
        "sectick", "Ticker",
        c(unique(Input$Ticker))
      ),
      dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
      dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
      selectInput(
        "aminv", "Amount Invested",
        c(unique(Input$`Amount Invested`))
      ),
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit"),
      
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
      
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3("Results"),
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "InsiderTraining",
          dataTableOutput("TBL1")
        )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # Init with some example data
    data <- reactiveVal(Input)
    rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL)
    
    observeEvent(
      input$add,
      {
        # start with current data
        data() %>%
          add_row(
            `Security Type` = isolate(input$sectype),
            Ticker = isolate(input$sectick),
            `Purchase Date` = isolate(input$PurDate),
            `Sale Date` = isolate(input$selDate),
            `Amount Invested` = isolate(input$aminv)
          ) %>%
          # update data value
          data()
      }
    )
    observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        data(data()[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected),])
        
      }
    })
    observeEvent(input$edit,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
        colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
        "remember the row selected"
        rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
        
        walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
        
      }
      
    })
    output$TBL1 <- renderDataTable(
      data(),selection="single"
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Do you want to keep using the reactiveVal `data()` for storing the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `reactiveValues`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  "$10,000",
  "$8,000", "$10,000"
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F, collapsed = F,
      selectInput(
        "sectype", "Security Type",
        c(unique(Input$`Security Type`))
      ),
      selectInput(
        "sectick", "Ticker",
        c(unique(Input$Ticker))
      ),
      dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
      dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
      selectInput(
        "aminv", "Amount Invested",
        c(unique(Input$`Amount Invested`))
      ),
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit"),
      
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
      
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3("Results"),
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "InsiderTraining",
          dataTableOutput("TBL1")
        )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )), ###### SERVER
  server = function(input, output) {
    # Init with some example data
    #data <- reactiveVal(Input)
    rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL) 
    
    observeEvent(
      input$add,
      {
        # start with current data
        rv$df <- rv$df %>%
          add_row(
            `Security Type` = isolate(input$sectype),
            Ticker = isolate(input$sectick),
            `Purchase Date` = isolate(input$PurDate),
            `Sale Date` = isolate(input$selDate),
            `Amount Invested` = isolate(input$aminv)
          )#  %>%
          # update data value
          #data()
          
        
      }
    )
    observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        #data(data()[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected),])
        rv$df <- rv$df[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected), ]
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$edit,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
        colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
        "remember the row selected"
        rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
        
        walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
        
      }
      
    })
    output$TBL1 <- renderDataTable(
      rv$df,selection="single"
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: I have a Q based on your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218070/update-widget-values-based-on-datatable-row-selection