# Update widget values based on datatable row selection

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny app below in which I can add a row with the values of the widgets or select a row and delete it. Also if I click on a row and the change a widget value and press `Edit` the relative cell value is changing.

What I want to add is when I click on a row all the widget values to be replaced by the relative selected row values.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  10000,
  8000, 10000
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F, collapsed = F,
      textInput(
        "sectype", "Security Type",
        "Stock")
      ,
      textInput(
        "sectick", "Ticker",
        "XOM")
      ,
      dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
      dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
      numericInput(
        "aminv", "Amount Invested",
        10000)
      ,
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit"),
      
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
      
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3("Results"),
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "InsiderTraining",
          dataTableOutput("TBL1")
        )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )), ###### SERVER
  server = function(input, output) {
    # Init with some example data
    #data <- reactiveVal(Input)
    rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL) 
    
    observeEvent(
      input$add,
      {
        # start with current data
        rv$df <- rv$df %>%
          add_row(
            `Security Type` = isolate(input$sectype),
            Ticker = isolate(input$sectick),
            `Purchase Date` = isolate(input$PurDate),
            `Sale Date` = isolate(input$selDate),
            `Amount Invested` = isolate(input$aminv)
          )#  %>%
        # update data value
        #data()
        
        
      }
    )
    observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        #data(data()[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected),])
        rv$df <- rv$df[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected), ]
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$edit,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
        colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
        "remember the row selected"
        rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
        
        walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
        
      }
      
    })
    output$TBL1 <- renderDataTable(
      rv$df,selection="single"
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: The ui is throwing this error: `Error in dashboardPage(options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE), header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading",  : 
  unused arguments (options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE), controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300))`

Comment: try now plz friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add an observer that every time a row is selected (in this case only one at a time) then the Widgets will update to the values contained in that row.

Since all widgets display only one value we can use `exec` and loop through all of them like this:

Beware that missing values (like in the second row) will produce the widget to be empty.

```
##### UPDATE WIDGETS WITH SELECTED ROW ######
widgts_nms <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
update_funs <- c('updateTextInput', 'updateTextInput', 'updateDateInput', 'updateDateInput', 'updateNumericInput')
#This will happen automatically on row click.
observe({
  req(input$TBL1_rows_selected)
  
  vals <- rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ]
  
  pwalk(list(update_funs, widgts_nms, vals), ~ exec(..1, !!!list(inputId = ..2, value = ..3[1]),.env = ))
  
})
```

[image]

app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(fontawesome)
library(tidyverse)

Input <- structure(list(`Security Type` = c("Stock", "Stock", "Load Fund"), Ticker = c("XOM", "NFLX", "AMCPX"), `Purchase Date` = structure(c(
  16070,
  17084, 17084
), class = "Date"), `Sale Date` = structure(c(
  18627,
  NA, 18545
), class = "Date"), `Amount Invested` = c(
  10000,
  8000, 10000
)), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
  "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class = "skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPage(
    options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "Investment Advisor Monitoring - Insider Trading", titleWidth = 450),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F, collapsed = F,
      textInput(
        "sectype", "Security Type",
        "Stock")
      ,
      textInput(
        "sectick", "Ticker",
        "XOM")
      ,
      dateInput("PurDate", "Purchase Date", value = as.Date("2013-12-31")),
      dateInput("selDate", "Sale Date", value = as.Date("2019-01-31")),
      numericInput(
        "aminv", "Amount Invested",
        10000)
      ,
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit"),
      
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows")
      
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      h3("Results"),
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel(
          "InsiderTraining",
          dataTableOutput("TBL1")
        )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(width = 300),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  )), ###### SERVER
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(df = Input, row_selected = NULL) 
    
    observeEvent(
      input$add,
      {
        
        rv$df <- rv$df %>%
          add_row(
            `Security Type` = isolate(input$sectype),
            Ticker = isolate(input$sectick),
            `Purchase Date` = isolate(input$PurDate),
            `Sale Date` = isolate(input$selDate),
            `Amount Invested` = isolate(input$aminv)
          )
       
        
        
        
      }
    )
    observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        rv$df <- rv$df[-as.numeric(input$TBL1_rows_selected), ]
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$edit,{
      
      if (!is.null(input$TBL1_rows_selected)) {
        cols_to_edit <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
        colnms <- c('Security Type', 'Ticker', 'Purchase Date', 'Sale Date', 'Amount Invested')
        "remember the row selected"
        rv$row_selected <- input$TBL1_rows_selected
        
        walk2(cols_to_edit, colnms, ~{rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ..2] <<- input[[..1]]}) 
        
      }
    })
      
      
      ##### UPDATE WIDGETS WITH SELECTED ROW ######
      widgts_nms <- c('sectype', 'sectick', 'PurDate', 'selDate', 'aminv')
      update_funs <- c('updateTextInput', 'updateTextInput', 'updateDateInput', 'updateDateInput', 'updateNumericInput')
      #This will happen automatically on row click.
      observe({
        req(input$TBL1_rows_selected)
        
        vals <- rv$df[input$TBL1_rows_selected, ]
        
        pwalk(list(update_funs, widgts_nms, vals), ~ exec(..1, !!!list(inputId = ..2, value = ..3[1]),.env = ))
        
      })
      
      
      
    
    output$TBL1 <- renderDataTable(
      rv$df,selection = "single"
    )
  }
  
)
```